# Get the X509 certificate from Amazon in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, x509certificate

I am using Amazon SNS (Simple Notification Service) to notify me with some data. Before i use the data sent, i want to authenticate if the data has not been tampered with.

Can someone please point me how i can get a X509 certificate from Amazon. I have the certificate URL from where i need to 'Retrieve the certificate' and then get Public Key from it which will be used to verify data.

I have tried various options but haven't come across any solution with actually retrieves certificate to get Public Key

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  If you're worried that the http or email destination is public, what about making the payload a reference to a more secure days store?  For example, write the data to s3 under a uuid and then write the uuid to sns.  If anyone tries to send an invalid uuid, it won't be present on s3.

Comment: I don't understand your comment at all: *I can always download this certificate and get the key (maybe that's the way Amazon is expecting me to do it) but i was thinking of doing it the way i have raised my question* ... huh?  You download the cert and extract the key... how else would you do this?

Comment: sorry, if i wasn't clear. what i meant was:- download certificate using c# code and then getting public key from it in a same code rather than manually downloading and saving the certificate somewhere and getting public key (which is easy). i couldn't find a way to get certificate using c# code.